# Why does my contract's function require so much gas when using the VRFConsumerBaseV2?

Tags: gas, chainlink, vrf

I am trying to make a Coinflip contract but when I call flipCoin the gas requred is 0.02 ETH and I dont know why?

I have followed this [tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/intermediates-tutorial/) and copied this [code](https://remix.ethereum.org/#url=https://docs.chain.link/samples/VRF/VRFD20.sol&optimize=false&runs=200&evmVersion=null&version=soljson-v0.8.7+commit.e28d00a7.js)

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x0b7102D95e1600Aa4A6C161D7311c144321c0CA5#writeContract

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol';
import '@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol';

/**
 * @notice A Chainlink VRF consumer which uses randomness to mimic the flipping
 * of a coin
 */

contract Coinflip is VRFConsumerBaseV2 {
    uint256 private constant FLIP_IN_PROGRESS = 42;

    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface COORDINATOR;

    uint64 s_subscriptionId;
    address vrfCoordinator = 0x6168499c0cFfCaCD319c818142124B7A15E857ab;
    bytes32 s_keyHash = 0xd89b2bf150e3b9e13446986e571fb9cab24b13cea0a43ea20a6049a85cc807cc;
    uint32 callbackGasLimit = 40000;
    uint16 requestConfirmations = 3;
    uint32 numWords = 1;

    mapping(uint256 => address) private flippers;
    mapping(address => uint256) private results;
    mapping(address => uint256) private guess;
    mapping(address => uint256) private staked;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;

    event CoinFlipped(uint256 indexed requestId, address indexed roller);
    event CoinLanded(uint256 indexed requestId, uint256 indexed result);
    event Withdrawal(address player, uint256 amount);

    /**
     * @notice Constructor inherits VRFConsumerBaseV2
     *
     * @param subscriptionId subscription id that this consumer contract can use
     */
    constructor(uint64 subscriptionId) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinator) {
        COORDINATOR = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinator);
        s_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
    }

    /**
     * @notice Requests randomness
     * @dev Warning: if the VRF response is delayed, avoid calling requestRandomness repeatedly
     * as that would give miners/VRF operators latitude about which VRF response arrives first.

     * @dev You must review your implementation details with extreme care.
     *
     * @param _guess address of the flipper
     */
    function flipCoin(uint256 _guess) public payable returns (uint256 requestId) {
        require(results[msg.sender] != 42, 'Flip in progress.');
        require(msg.value < address(this).balance, 'Amount is greater than contract balance.');

        requestId = COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
            s_keyHash,
            s_subscriptionId,
            requestConfirmations,
            callbackGasLimit,
            numWords
        );

        flippers[requestId] = msg.sender;
        guess[msg.sender] = _guess;
        staked[msg.sender] = msg.value;
        results[msg.sender] = FLIP_IN_PROGRESS;

        emit CoinFlipped(requestId, msg.sender);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Callback function used by VRF Coordinator to return the random number to this contract.
     *
     * @dev Some action on the contract state should be taken here, like storing the result.
     * @dev WARNING: take care to avoid having multiple VRF requests in flight if their order of arrival would result
     * in contract states with different outcomes. Otherwise miners or the VRF operator would could take advantage
     * by controlling the order.
     * @dev The VRF Coordinator will only send this function verified responses, and the parent VRFConsumerBaseV2
     * contract ensures that this method only receives randomness from the designated VRFCoordinator.
     *
     * @param requestId uint256
     * @param randomWords  uint256[] The random result returned by the oracle.
     */
    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 requestId, uint256[] memory randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 coinFlippedValue = (randomWords[0] % 2);
        address flipper = flippers[requestId];

        if (guess[flipper] == coinFlippedValue) {
            balances[flipper] += staked[flipper]*2;
        }

        emit CoinLanded(requestId, coinFlippedValue);
    }

    /**
     * @notice Player can withdraw staked funds
     * @param player address
     */
    function withdraw(address payable player) public payable {
        uint256 balance = balances[player];
        if (balances[player] >= address(this).balance) {
            balances[player] -= address(this).balance;
            player.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
        else {
            player.transfer(balance);
            balances[player] = 0;
        }
        
        emit Withdrawal(player, balance);
    }

}
```

Thanks, Jocko.

Comment: What is the gas cost? Same gas cost may end up with different ether amount due to the gas price, how did you get the value of  0.02ETH?

Answer (score 0):

Is the transaction successful or do you get a warning message on metamask when executing the function?

If the code is right, then it's probably because that's the cost to run that function. You could try reducing the gas price. That's about it.